# Session Start Failure

Tags: php, session, autostart

This is not your average session failed to start question, there is no whitespace, i have not called it in another file etc.

Im currently working on an application as I have started to build my session library, now when I call `session_start` I get the following error:

> A session had already been started - ignoring `session_start()`

For those who wish to see the source: https://github.com/AdminSpot/ASFramework/blob/master/system/libraries/session.php

This usually means that the session.autostart directive is set to `1`, but that's the thing.. it's not, it's set to 0 and I have verified this by doing the following:

- Search my entire system for `php.ini*` files, checked them
- Executed the following command `php --ini` amd validated the ini files
- executed the following command `php -i | grep session.auto_start`. which responded with `session.auto_start => Off => Off`
- Checked the PHPInfo page, see image below
- Checked the php.ini files for cgi
- There is no htaccess files on nginx
- `grep -lir "session_start" *` only shows my library file
- Restarting FastCGI, Nginx and the entire server

I have created a basic test script to test where i have just called session start on it's own.

The `phpinfo()` call stats the active php.ini is `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` so after running `cat /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini | grep session.auto_start` I get `session.auto_start = 0`, so it disabled, Could it be NGinx ?

Has anyone got any idea what's going on, some server information below:

- PHP: PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch
- MySQL: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.54, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
- Nginx: Version: nginx/0.8.54

PHPInfo screen:

[image]

Comment: I know you checked the ini's but did you do `phpinfo();` to verify `autostart` setting?

Comment: yes sorry that has been verified, see screen above

Comment: Sorry to be picky but did you run `phpinfo();` on the line right before you call `session_start()`? That is the best place to run it. If you did, then `auto_start` is not your problem.

Comment: i only change 2 directives: https://github.com/AdminSpot/ASFramework/blob/master/system/init.php

Comment: Random thought: is /var/lib/php5 owned by apache (per this post http://fryshadow.blogspot.com/2010/11/nginx-phpmyadmin-php-cannot-start.html)?

Comment: well it has to be owned by root, im executing the fast-cgi as root telling it to access and read web files under the www-data, doing that would meen if someone got a shell on my site they can access my php directory and add root perms, mess my security up but thanks anyway, i did check the permissions and there all ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be that you have an [auto-prepend file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) or an .htaccess which is modifying the settings in the meanwhile.

You can use `ini_get` to retrieve the value of session.auto_start and auto_prepend_file to confirm. phpinfo() should work too.

### Edit

Could it be that your session library is being instantiated twice? Since return `$this->session_started` is an instance variable, that could cause issues. What happens if you set that to a class-level variable?

Side note:
You also have this `return $this->session_started = true;` at the end of the `start()` method. It shouldn't matter, but it looks funny.

Comment: Ok, saw your PHP info block above. Have you checked `auto_prepend_file`.

Comment: yea the side note is pointless, and no in regards to calling twice, as the `$this->start();` is called by the constructor, and this is loaded once by: https://github.com/AdminSpot/ASFramework/blob/master/system/classes/base/classloader.class.php#L44

Comment: Iv'e , Marked your answer as correct because ultimately the class was being loaded twice, due to an overlook of a function, i was using `in_array` rather then `array_key_exists`, see: https://github.com/AdminSpot/ASFramework/blob/master/system/classes/base/classloader.class.php#L23 and thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about .htaccess containing a `php_value session.auto_start 1`?  PHP on the command line would totally ignore settings overrides in .htaccess files. Remember that commandline PHP and web-based PHP have completely different .ini files in most standard configurations, so checking via command line is a waste of time.

I'd suggest having your script do a `phpinfo()` immediately before one of your session_start calls and check what the effective settings are there.

Comment: im using Nginx, and no there are no htaccess, yea i used the command line to get the directory of the active php files, as im using CGI i checked the files accordingly.

Comment: Either way, do a phpinfo() in one of the scripts causing this error, immediately before the session_start() call. It'll show you exactly what the current settings are, and which .ini files are in use.

Comment: Hmm. just saw your phpinfo update above. About all i can think of is to rummage through your entire system for PHP files and check if they have a session_start() call in them, and figure out if they're being included/required somehow in your site.

Comment: Yea i have created a blank php file within a separate location and fired it and still does the same, this does not seem to a problem with the app, but with PHP.

Comment: Check for auto_prepend_file, as cwallenpoole's stated. It could including a file which does session_start(), so the phpinfo looks normal, but the session is still being started automatically due to the auto-include.

Comment: @MarcB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1158/discussion-between-robertpitt-and-marc-b)

Comment: @Mark B, So System said take it to chat, And thanks for your support anyway.

Answer (score 0):

And anyway you can just verify if a session has already started or not.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}
```

Comment: this is not the answer i was looking for, im aware of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#90007

Check and see if you are being passed a session cookie. May help you narrow it down.

Comment: There is a `PHPSESSID` cookie, obviously because there is a session, this does not make any difference to why the session is being started in the first place :/

Comment: And you said you've tried a new file with just `session_start()`, correct?

Comment: yes, ive also checked my entire application using `grep -lir "session_start" *` and it only states that the session library contains the function.

Comment: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html#session_protection

Since the patch protects the session data, is there a chance it opens a session on all files, regardless of the settings?

Comment: ive always used suhosin and never had a problem, and also i have not added any directives for suhosin to manage the session security such as `suhosin.session.encrypt` as there not set.